# Android Intent-Filter for https Appwrite Cloud

Tags: java, android, appwrite

My app didn't open Activity when I open link from appwrite cloud. Google Chrome open this link and I don't know why. Maybe trouble in `android:pathPattern`?
Why it's don't be able to open Link?

Link example: https://cloud.appwrite.io/?membershipId=64a14b25edd52bb71c5b&userId=649f12deb0f48214eacc&secret=c84c3a175c5f176038072dcf7b0388c159dc9a5b7c3605d52780ff2acbeb65d9bb2cd23da337b53e0357bf93c01aec61354a06ec7a531a52e5d3bc8c07338a37fdf9e923fb0f58d0dc3851f0e87d46fa55606034938a77e4acc198a5394b2502bd925e921793dfd166c4040bc0bbddce7f4814bf12b24a97134d2ae7e040ff93&teamId=64985d8f02dee0a84ed7

My app manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".FriendsActivity"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError">
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"
                    tools:ignore="AppLinkUrlError" />
                <data android:host="cloud.appwrite.io" android:pathPattern="/?" android:scheme="http"/>
                <data android:host="cloud.appwrite.io" android:pathPattern="/?" android:scheme="https"/>
                <data android:host="cloud.appwrite.io" android:pathPattern="/?" android:scheme="android-app"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I'm tried to use other host and `android:autoVerify="true"`, but this don't help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be able to use `android:autoVerify="true"` because you can't verify cloud.appwrite.io since you don't own the domain.

Also, you should use your domain for deep linking so that you can verify it.